# iOS UITableView that uses multi level to display a Detailed View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Creating an APP that has multi levels of UITableView  x 3 and a detailed view...

Car Manufacturer - TableView List

VW, Ford...etc...  (then goes to next - Type of Car UITableView List)

Type of Car - TableView List = 
MPV, Salon, Racing...etc...  (then select - Type --- from this TableView List - Next it is to UITableView List the Model of cars

UITableView List - Models  -   Select the Model from the Model TableView List =

More Details of it.... View Controller.... Details
Title, Image, Description = maybe an - Array of Text - for a UITextView

Other facts:
CO2 - goes to a label, Mpg - goes to a label

---

Thinking about a Sqlite Database / local to the iPhone / iPad...

manufacturer    / type  / model / imagename / description   / cotwo / mpg

Ford    / Salon / Escort    / escort.jpg    / Escort car made in 1972.  / 100 co2   / 25

VW  / MPV   / Tourvan   / vwtourvan.jpg / The tourvan has 7 seats.  / 80 co2    / 50.4

---

What is the best method in doing this?

I can do a basic UITableView to a Detailed View...,  Or is it best to use Core Data, that as I move across the "Storyboard" via reference from database of Manufacturers, to the types of cars, goes to new Controllers and changes the data displayed...

Looking for a best way, so I can google it or any pointing in the right direction...

Cheers Simon

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

Using table view/detail view and core data don't need to be mutually exclusive.

The decision whether to use core data to store your car data would depend on how much/often/easiness that you want to change or update your car info.  If you are going to cover all cars made on earth.... use core data!

Comment: Thanks, will be looking at Core Data - as it can be less or as you say more info to load and keep it easy to see... plus update more info from me or the end user...  Cool...